# Unable to load image from Jar

Tags: java, image, jar, swt

I'm trying to load an image from a Jar File. Here's the line:

```
Image imgTrayIcon = new Image(display, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.ico"));
```

I've seen many examples using this method but when I try to do so, I get and error saying that my image is invalid. Here's the stack trace:

```
 [java] Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid image
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.WinICOFileFormat.loadInfoHeader(WinICOFileFormat.java:200)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.WinICOFileFormat.loadIcon(WinICOFileFormat.java:127)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.WinICOFileFormat.loadFromByteStream(WinICOFileFormat.java:119)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.FileFormat.loadFromStream(FileFormat.java:48)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.FileFormat.load(FileFormat.java:84)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.load(ImageLoader.java:130)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageDataLoader.load(ImageDataLoader.java:22)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.<init>(ImageData.java:331)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:545)
 [java]     at SysTray.run(Unknown Source)
```

The icon I'm using is definitely valid. I've checked this using icon tools. I've also tried placing the icon in the same directory as my code (not Jar-ing it) and using it like this:

```
Image imgTrayIcon = new Image(display, "icon.ico");
```

This works just fine, but when I try to put it in the Jar, it doesn't. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I've uncompressed my Jar to check whether the file was added to the Jar and it seems to be there. My jar doesn't has any complex folder structure. All the files and resources are in the same level of tree.

Any ideas on what's wrong here? Thanks

---

Here's some sample code to replicate the issue:

Example.java

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;

class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Image imgTrayIcon = new Image(display, Example.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icon.ico"));
    }

}
```

Commands:

```
javac -cp "SWT.jar" Example.java
jar cf Example.jar *.class *.ico
java -cp "Example.jar;SWT.jar" Example
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are working on multi-threaded application. 
From the stack-trace `Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid image` it appears that you are loading the image in a non-ui thread and trying to use that in some UI element. [See this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/340970/GUI/java/swt-threads).

Within a UI thread the below code works fine. (The icon file is inside the `test package`)

```
package test;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class IconTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        shell.setLocation(20, 20);

        InputStream stream = IconTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/test/icon.ico"); 

        Image imgTrayIcon = new Image(display, stream);

        shell.setImage(imgTrayIcon);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                        display.sleep();
        }

        if(imgTrayIcon != null)
            imgTrayIcon.dispose();

        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Favonius. I think I found the reason. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the threads, etc. My icon is a multi-resolution icon. I can use this icon just fine if i load it load it directly but it seems that loading a multi-resolution icon from the resources causes issues. Do you know anything about this? I tried my example using a simple icon file, which had just one resolution and it worked just fine. Here is the icon i was trying to use: http://findicons.com/icon/64852/download_box?id=345962 .

Comment: Seems like a bug in SWT implementation. The code fails even if `InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("icon.ico");`. P.S. The problem is with the multi-resolution icon. **But** when you do `imgTrayIcon = new Image(display, "icon.ico");` then SWT calls a native method... which in turn calls a native win32 GDI+ API. You may wish to look for an SWT bug... if couldn't find any then raise one !!

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon image = (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("yourpackage/mypackage/image.gif")));
```

In general, you can retrieve an InputStream in the following way:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader()    .getResourceAsStream("yourpackage/mypackage/myfile.xml");
```

It will run inside or outside the jar.

refer http://www.jugpadova.it/articles/2006/02/05/accessing-a-resource-within-a-jar

also refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. If I try to load an `ImageIcon`, it works i.e. I don't see any errors. I have an SWT application and am not using Swing widgets.

Comment: its just an example important thing is the way to specify getClass().getResource("yourpackage/mypackage/image.gif")

Comment: Yup, I understood that bit but I don't have any package structure inside my Jar. All the files are on the the same level and am therefore referring to it like this : `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icon.ico");`. I've checked that the file exists in the Jar by running `jar tf <filename.jar>`. I still get the same error though.

Comment: I've added some sample code to my post to show what I'm doing.

Comment: try to add the jar application name before the image name as i have created sampleapplication and created jar by inserting an image into it the folder structure for image was sampleapplication/myimage.ico

Answer (score 0):

Try these - 
`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icon.ico")`
OR
`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("package_or_full_path_to_image/icon.ico"
)`
OR
`Name_of_THIS_CLASS.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icon.ico")`

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried putting the file in the same directory as the class file, without Jaring it, and using `getResourceAsStream()` to load it?
2. Have you tried getting a checksum of the stream using [java.security.DigestInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/DigestInputStream.html) while inside and outside of the Jar, to see if the file actually differs in any way between the two environments?